# Set text outline color

Tags: rust, sdl-2

I was looking through the docs and found `<font>.set_outline_width(number)` and I was wondering: how do I set the color (I am assuming this is possible but the docs don't have anything on it)

```
let mut timer_font = self
    .ttf
    .load_font("assets/HyliaSerifBeta-Regular.otf", 60)
    .expect("could not open font file");
let mut font = self
    .ttf
    .load_font("assets/HyliaSerifBeta-Regular.otf", 25)
    .expect("could not open font file");
timer_font.set_outline_color(Color::RGB(0,0,0); //returns error (duh)
timer_font.set_outline_width(10);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119642/how-to-use-sdl-ttfs-outlines) indicates you cannot set a separate outline color, but you can achieve that effect by drawing the text twice: one with the outline, the other without.

Comment: Hmm; so outline text is just an overlay? Got it!